# What is a proper term for the contamination of a language?

Tags: terminology

Italians, for some reason, tend to accept and use foreign terms quite easily. The foreign terms that have entered and are entering common usage are mainly from the English language. Their usage has been increasing so consistently in recent years that that main Italian language authority " l'Accademia della Crusca" has raised an official allarm regarding the 'invasion' of foreign terminology.

According to a recent study , the usage of English terms has increased by 773% in the last 8 years. L'Accademia has made a petition to '[Save the Italian Language](http://www.i-siena.it/2015/02/salviamo-la-lingua-italiana-dallinvasione-inglese-vola-la-petizione/) ' and will officially ask the Italian Government, Public Administrations, Media  and Public Companies to limit their use of foreign words and favour  the Italian equivalent terms instead.

Whether  this initiative will be successful or not (I really doubt it), this phenomenon is going to continue for years. I think it is a social-psycho-linguistic issue. That's why I am asking here what is a proper, correct term to define it.

P.S. This question is open also  [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/salviamo-la-lingua-italiana) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233187/an-appropriate-term-for-the-contamination-of-a-language).

Comment: Strictly political. The language is not being "contaminated" (consider the presuppositions of that word in a title, by the way), but enriched. Look at how many times official language groups have made fools of themselves by forbidding and proclaiming and being ignored. Look up the story of King Knut (Canute in English) and his relative power to the tides. Languages are not changed consciously; they are changed quite unconsciously, by people and in ways that have nothing whatsoever to do with "The Language" and its erstwhile "defenders" or "cleansers".

Comment: @johnlawlerinexile, you are mostly right, however there are several exceptions. Off the top of my mind: (1) there are languages with *prescriptive* grammar and morphology (unlike *descriptive* one), e.g. Russian; (2) languages with unbound morphemes (Chinese) also tend to prefer local equivalents versus loanwords. In other words, I can easily imagine "Save Our Language" movements in these countries.

Comment: @bytebuster, what do you mean by "there are languages with prescriptive grammar and morphology (unlike descriptive one), e.g. Russian?"

Comment: @AlexB. Descriptive grammar refers to the structure of a language as it is actually used by native speakers.
Prescriptive grammar refers to the structure of a language as certain people think it should be used.

Comment: Are you asking for the term **borrowing**?

Comment: @bytebuster what makes Russian distinct, then? Grammar *texts* can be descriptive or prescriptive. The grammar of a language, in and of itself, is neither. It's like letter vs spirit of the law — that's a perspective taken by the people who interpret the law, not the law itself.

Comment: I'm not going to delete the question, but [you can request to be disassociated from it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239366/176533). Please read that post (and comments) carefully. This is meant as an exception.

Comment: Isn't the question here clearly "How do you call the phenomenon of speakers of one language increasingly using words of another language without using a loaded word like contamination"? That's how I understood this

Comment: @johnlawlerinexile Sure you can change language consciously, the Académie Francaise does that and government officials do it when they promote gender-conscious language or prohibit offensive terms. The fact that they are frequently less successful than they wish they were doesn't mean they don't change the language at all. Just because I can't push a car as far as I'd like to doesn't mean I can't push it at all.

Comment: @bytebuster, I wasn't asking about prescriptive vs. descriptive grammar. I wanted to understand what you meant by "there are languages with prescriptive grammar."

Answer (score 5):

The neutral phrase for this phenomenon is **language contact** which is one of the ways in which [language change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_change) can occur.

What you have reported in your question is a matter of (having a wrong) perspective. I used to dislike the seemingly vast amount of loanwords, so I can understand those that don't like it, but I changed my mind. Consider this: you're living *now*, so your perspective comes from what is happening now. You (a general you) learned a certain language that you call Italian since your childhood, with a specific vocabulary. During your life you've experienced an acquisition of foreign terms, so from your perspective it's been "contaminated" (for lack of a better word) by other languages.

However this is a false perspective because the "base language" you learned as Italian is not "pure" at all. It's the result of all the previous influences and borrowings; there is no such thing as truly, 100% pure language. There are more welcoming and less welcoming languages, so to speak, but you won't find a truly immutable, pure language, at least not in the Information Age we're in. Geographically isolated languages might show a higher degree of "purity", but they can still be influenced, because that's the very nature of languages.

Going back to my previous statement, the Italian you learned is full of borrowed words that you think are perfectly Italian. Just to name a few:

- Gazzella (gazelle), comes from Arabic *ghazāl*
- Cifra (digit, number), comes from Arabic *ṣifr*
- Bistecca comes from *beef steak*
- Manichino comes from fr. *mannequin*
- Fiordo, comes from Norwegian *fjord*
- Grattacielo is a calque from English *skyscraper*

There's even cliccare, a verb formed by attaching the verb ending -are to the root *clic*, from English *to click.*

English has acquired many terms from Italian as well: opera, stanza, pianissimo, a cappella, falsetto, but [I could really go on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Italian_origin). It's also not a coincidence that these terms are all related music and theatre. Italian has been the Lingua Franca in Europe in the past, such as during the Renaissance, and many terms are still used in present day.

It should be mentioned that many loanwords stay side by side with the local terms, such as is the case with those that are used in defined contexts: The English term *corner* is used in soccer matches only, as far as Italian is concerned, while the corresponding word *angolo* is used for all instances (including soccer too at will).

In conclusion: languages change, and one of the ways they do is to assimilate foreign terms. That's just what they do. Trying to "save" a language can be good when the native speakers are dying out, but in this case it's kind of pointless.

Comment: I agree that borrowings like bistecca and cifra is an instance of language change, but if that is "the answer", then the question is mis-worded. The question talks extensively about L'Accademia's campaign to save the language from foreign words. The natural interpretation of the "it" which is being asked about would be the attitude expressed by L'Accademia and similar institutions. Focusing on L'Accademia makes no sense if the question is about the process of borrowing. We can only deal with the question asked, not the asker's intent.

Comment: @user6726 I think that whole thing about l'Accademia and the petition was to provide some context although it ended up catching more attention than the actual question. I think he was asking how to call the "borrowing", and that is Language contact that results in Language change. Maybe I should specify this.

Comment: @user6726 Considering that the name of the question is "What is a proper term for the contamination of a language" and that the natural antecedent for "it" in the question is "this phenomenon", it seems safe to assume that the asker was not asking about the name of the Accademia's mindset but about a non-loaded term like _borrowing_.

Answer (score 3):

This is an instance of xenophobia: there isn't a specific terms that relates to languages, because it's never just fear of foreign words, it's always paired with fear of any kind of foreign thing.

Comment: No, I am sorry. As I clearly said in my question, Italians are quite at ease with this issue. The concern of the Accademia is merely a linguistic one.

Comment: An individual or small group can be xenophobic, even in a very non-xenophobic society.

Comment: Agreed.., but that is another issue!!

Comment: The Accademia is even more political than the politicians; the politicians don't care. But the Accademia is fighting for its turf. And losing.

Comment: How exactly did you find out that all the people showing dislike of loanwords are fearful of any kind of foreign thing? Did you ask them all? My brother regularly scolds me for using English terms where there is an appropriate German one, yet I have never seen a person I'd be less likely to describe as xenophobic.

Comment: @MaxP: -phobia is used not just for fear, but also for aversion, antipathy or dislike (someone who is *photophobic* is not scared of the light). To wit, OED defines xenophobia as an *antipathy*, not a fear. If he has a strong dislike for foreign terms because they are foreign, he is, by definition, xenophobic *with respect to the German language*.

Comment: @guifa a) then xenophobia is not by definition a bad thing, and b) user6726 explicitly talks about "fear of any king of foreign thing" and c) user6726 says that "it's never just fear of foreign words". Apart from them you can dislike foreign terms because they are an unneccessary addition, they are often used as an attention grab or because you feel using a foreign term because you can't think of the native one shows inferior command of your language. One of these reasons is traditionalist, one is aesthetic and one is slightly snobbish, but neither is xenophobic.

Comment: I can say I don't like people with dark colored skin because it's not aesthetically pleasing.  It would still make me a racist even though it might have nothing to do with the race directly.  If you don't like foreign words, you are a xenophobe with respect to language.  It doesn't matter *why*.  You may try to cover it up in other words, just as people xenophobes try to mask their views as nationalist or preservationist, but they're still xenophobes with respect to people/politics.

Comment: @guifa Not liking the use of certain foreign words in certain contexts is not the same as not liking them at all. If I were replacing every second word in this comment with its Swahili counterpart, you wouldn't like that. Does that make you a xenophobe?

Comment: @MaxP yes, because not liking Africans in some parts of the world is not as racist as not looking them in any part of the world =\ Replacing every other word with a Swahili word that has not been imported into English  is simply unintelligible. If I knew the meaning of those words — and even moreso if they have become an accepted part of a speech community —  then yes, it would absolutely make me a xenophobe, I'm rejecting something that's perfectly good and acceptable exclusively on the basis that it's foreign.

Comment: But that's exactly the point. We are talking about words that haven't 'become an accepted part of a speech community'. I'm not talking about using words like 'chatroom' or 'computer' that everyone uses. But to give you an example where the dislike of foreign words is - in my opinion - justified, is when newspapers, cereal boxes and (worst of all) statements from schools and teachers use English terms to come across young and hip. It's just an attention grab and a misunderstanding of the ways youths talk, so I dislike it. It doesn't work with native words, so I only dislike foreign words there.

Comment: @MaxP We **are** dealing with words that have been accepted by their speech communities.  The OP clearly indicates that the Italian people understand them and they use them with preferences to any nativist terminology.  That's as clear an indicator of societal acceptance of the terminology as I can think of.

Comment: @guifa It clearly isn't. People with basic English skills can (and often will) replace basically any term with an English term and make themselves understood. That doesn't mean the term itself has become an accepted part of the speech community, or you'd have to add the entire basic English lexicon to "words accepted by the speech community". And you might also say that if the Accademia is so furiously trying to fight this, at least in some parts of the speech community it isn't accepted. The fact that some people do something (or even all occasionally) doesn't make it generally accepted.

Comment: @guifa This discussion is getting out of hand. We both clearly agree that user6726 is wrong when saying that if you dislike foreign words, it's always paired with fear of any foreign thing, since you are talking specifically about "xenophobia with respect to language". For me, there is a clear moral difference between judging people by their origin or their aesthetics and judging words by those aspects, so using xenophobia (which has connotations of being clearly and disgustingly wrong) in respect to language is strange to me. You seem to disagree on one of these points. Lets leave it at that.